# SFML 2.0 equivalent of SetFromRect()?

Tags: c++, view, camera, scroll, sfml

I need to find the equivalent of SetFromRect() for SFML 2.0. I'm using it in a camera class where I am updating the position of the rectangle where the sprite can move freely. Once it reaches the middle of the screen it will start scrolling the camera by re-updating the rectangle with the new co-ordinates.

```
void Camera::Update(int x, int y)
{
    cameraX = -(ScreenWidth / 2) + x;
    cameraY = -(ScreenHeight / 2) + y;

    std::cout << "cameraX: " << cameraX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cameraY: " << cameraY << std::endl;

    if(cameraX < 0)
        cameraX = 0;
    if(cameraY < 0)
        cameraY = 0;

    CameraPosition.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(cameraX, cameraY, cameraX + ScreenWidth, cameraY + ScreenHeight));
    std::cout << "cameraX + ScreenWidth: " << cameraX + ScreenWidth << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cameraY + ScreenWidth: " << cameraY + ScreenWidth << std::endl;
}
```

That all works fine except for:

```
CameraPosition.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(cameraX, cameraY, cameraX + ScreenWidth, cameraY + ScreenHeight));
```

It's obtaining all the right numbers but I think it's the wrong function for it.

I did try reset() but it didn't work either.

EDIT:

The correct code is:

```
CameraPosition.reset(sf::FloatRect(cameraX, cameraY, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
CameraPosition.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(0,0,1,1));
```

Comment: What type is CameraPosition and how is it being used by your RenderWindow?

Comment: CameraPosition is a sf::View and it is used by RenderWindow as so:

Comment: void Camera::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &Window)
{
    Window.setView(CameraPosition);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFML 2.0 rectangle types were changed from (left, top, right, bottom) to (left, top, width, height). I make that mistake too all the time.

To move the camera around all you need to do is to move the `sf::View`. In your code that is as simple as calling `CameraPosition.setCenter(x, y);`.

Comment: Edited the answer, should be what you were after.

Comment: 1) Did you replace all the code inside your function with `CameraPosition.setCenter(x, y);` ? 2) What exactly is happening? Camera not moving, black screen, camera moving weirdly etc?

Comment: The camera is not moving. I have a image bigger than the screen but the sprite just walks of the visible screen. I check the x and y of the sprite and it's working fine yet the camera doesn't actually scroll at all.

Comment: Tough. Hard to help you without seeing more code. First thing you should probably do is check that you can move the camera by hand (i.e. call `setView` with a view with a constant offset) and go from there.

Comment: Fixed it! The correct code is:                                             CameraPosition.reset(sf::FloatRect(cameraX, cameraY, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));              CameraPosition.setViewport(sf::FloatRect(0,0,1,1));